# Invariance of trace of a squared commutator under U(N) conjugation of one of its arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $N\times N$ matrices $A$ and $B$, how can one show that the trace of their commutator squared invariant under a conjugation of $B$ by any matrix $U \in U(N)$?

\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left([A,B]^2\right) \rightarrow \mathrm{tr}\left([A,UBU^{-1}]^2\right)\stackrel{!}{=}\mathrm{tr}\left([A,B]^2\right)
\end{align}

I've tried various applications of commutator identities and cyclicity under the trace but I consistently end up getting lost. I think there's a more obvious simplification I may be missing.

Comment: How do you know that this identity holds?

Comment: This isn't true. It should be easy to find some $A=B$ and $U$ such that $[A,UAU^{-1}]^2$ has a nonzero trace.

Comment: Consider $A,B$ to be two (different) Pauli matrices. Their commutator is (proportional to) another Pauli matrix whose square is the identity. On the other hand there exist a unitary that makes the two matrices equal, hence their commutator is zero.

Comment: I've asked a new question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4474780/409450, because I think I was mistaken in my attempt to generalize the expression that I really wanted to ask about. So, @BenGrossmann I'm pretty sure your skepticism was well placed. Icv, I think I understand your argument, it's for a more special case than this, and a more special case than the question I've linked above. Thanks though!