# Invariance of trace of a squared commutator under U(N) conjugation; SU(2) representations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Let the matrices $L_i$, with $i=1,2,3$, be the generators of $SU(2)$ in the $N$-dimensional irreducible representation. Then suppose I have an $N\times N$ Hermitian matrix $\phi$, I am trying to show that the following expression is invariant under a conjugation of the $\phi$ matrix by any $U \in U(N)$,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3[L_i,\phi]^2\right) \rightarrow \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3[L_i,U\phi U^{-1}]^2\right)\stackrel{!}{=}\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3[L_i,\phi]^2\right)
\end{align}

Here's my work so far,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3[L_i,U\phi U^{-1}]^2\right) &= \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i U\phi U^{-1} - U\phi U^{-1}L_i\right)^2\right)\\
&= \mathrm{tr}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i U\phi U^{-1} L_i U \phi U^{-1} - L_iL_i U \phi \phi U^{-1}\right)\right)
\end{align}

Working with just that second term,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left(-2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_iL_i U \phi \phi U^{-1}\right)\right) &= \mathrm{tr}\left(-2U \phi \phi U^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i^2) \right)\right)\\
&= \mathrm{tr}\left(-2U \phi \phi U^{-1}\alpha \right)\\
&= \mathrm{tr}\left(-2 \phi \phi\alpha \right)
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is a constant with value of $\frac{1}{4}(N-1)/2$ given by the Casimir operator in the $N$-dimensional representation. Note that this makes contact with the corresponding term in the the expansion of the un-transformed expression, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3[L_i,\phi ]^2\right) &= \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i \phi  - \phi L_i\right)^2\right)\\
&= \mathrm{tr}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i \phi L_i  \phi  - L_iL_i \phi \phi \right)\right)\\
&= \mathrm{tr}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i \phi L_i  \phi \right) \right) + \mathrm{tr}\left(-2\phi\phi\alpha\right)
\end{align}
This leaves us with
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{tr}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(\left[U^{-1}L_i U\right]\phi \left[U^{-1} L_i U\right] \phi \right)\right) &\stackrel{!}{=} \mathrm{tr}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^3\left(L_i \phi L_i  \phi \right) \right)
\end{align}
where I have used cyclicity and added brackets to rewrite the left-hand side emphasizing that we can view this as a $U(N)$ transformation of the $L_i$ matrices. It seems to me that this last expression should be true but I can't think of what to use to prove it.