# A relation for adjoint representation of $U(N)$ acting on product of matrices and $SU(2)$ generators.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Is the following relation true, and if so, what is the property that makes it so?
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i=1}^3\mathrm{tr}\left([U^{-1}L_iU]\phi[U^{-1}L_iU]\phi\right) \stackrel{!}{=} \sum_{i=1}^3\mathrm{tr}\left(L_i\phi L_i\phi\right)
\end{align}
where $\phi$ is an $N\times N$ Hermitian matrix, $L_i$ are the generators of $SU(2)$ in the $N$-dimensional irreducible representation, and $U \in U(N)$. For context, I arrived at this in trying to demonstrate the invariance of a more complicated expression under the $U(N)$ adjoint action appearing here: [Invariance of trace of a squared commutator under U(N) conjugation; SU(2) representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474780/invariance-of-trace-of-a-squared-commutator-under-un-conjugation-su2-repres).

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714726/a-relation-for-adjoint-representation-of-un-acting-on-product-of-matrices-an

Comment: Immediately I'm thinking of the cyclic property of trace, but that doesn't actually seem to help here. Still... something like that. If nothing else, break it down into indices and try to crunch through the computation. My suspicion is that this will be a general fact about matrices, and will have nothing to do with $SU(2)$, $U(N)$, etc. in particular.

Comment: I retract my previous statement. You probably will have to use unitarity, hermiticity, and maybe even special unitarity. Such things are useful when dealing with indices after all. The part that I think won't be relevant is that the $L_i$ are generatrs of $SU(2)$. Probably you'll just need to use the fact that the $L_i$ are Hermitian (or anti-Hermitian depending on how you define them).